# laravel 9: custom login process

Tags: php, laravel, authorization, laravel-9

I created a custom `guard` because I want to authorize users on a custom table. So I followed this guide: [tutorial](https://hackthestuff.com/article/laravel-multiple-authentication-system-using-different-models)

But in my custom Auth Controller if I use `auth()->user();` and then `redirect()->intended()` I get `419 PAGE EXPIRED`. If I use `Auth::login($user);` I can see that `Auth::check()` returns `true` but after the redirect the user is logged out.

Here is my `login` function in controller:

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        /*$this->validate($request, [
            'person_username' => 'required|username',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);*/
        $credentials = [
            'person_username' => 'readmin',
            'password' => 'c4ca42389a6f75849b'
        ];
        if(auth()->guard('myg')->attempt([
            'person_username' => $request->person_username,
            'password' => $request->password,
        ])) {
            //$user = auth()->user(); ->if I use this instead of the following lines I get 419 error
            $user = Fiperson::where('person_username', $credentials['person_username'])->first();
        Auth::login($user);
//if (Auth::check()) {dd('okkk');} //if I uncommment it I get 'okkk'
            return redirect()->intended(url('/admin/dashboard'));
        } else {
            return redirect()->back()->withError('Credentials doesn\'t match.');
        }
    }
```

And here are my route for successful login:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:myg']], function () {
    Route::get('admin/dashboard', [RegateController::class, 'dashboard'])->name('admin.dashboard');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead `auth()->user()` use `auth()->guard('myg')->user()` as default guard is set to web.

```
...
if(auth()->guard('myg')->attempt([
            'person_username' => $request->person_username,
            'password' => $request->password,
        ])) {
$user = auth()->guard('myg')->user();
Auth::guard('myg')->login($user);
...
```

Comment: I did that but now it redirects me to login screen. like is logged out. If I `dd($user)` I get `guarded[0] = '*'`